# Derivation of Variance of Variance estimator

Tags: variance, least-squares, econometrics

so far I do understand how to show that 
$$
\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{e'e}{n-k}
$$
is an unbiased variance estimator in the standard OLS model.

However, I don't know how to show that the variance of the estimator is the following:

$$
\mathbb{V}[\hat\sigma^2] = \frac{2\sigma^4}{n-k}
$$

Help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you figured out the distribution for $\hat{\sigma}^2$?

Comment: nope, i don't know what 

$$ \mathbb{V}[e'e] $$ is. I was trying the followig formula:

$$ \mathbb{V}[e^2] = \mathbb{E}[(e^2)^2]  -\mathbb{E}[e^2]^2 $$

But there I'm strunggling with $$\mathbb{E}[(e^2)^2]$$

Comment: The latter is the fourth moment of the distribution and depends on what distribution you assume for $e$.